Unknown Interaction Discord
I'm making a Discord bot that sends notifications (like when a stream is launched) and I created a command with which we can configure the channel where those notifications have to be sent, but I have a problem. When I do the command one time on Discord, it works, no problem, but when I do it a 2nd time in a row, an error appears in my terminal:
DiscordAPIError[10062]: Unknown interaction
    at handleErrors (E:\Bot Discord\Francis le Bot\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\index.js:722:13)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async BurstHandler.runRequest (E:\Bot Discord\Francis le Bot\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\index.js:826:23)
    at async _REST.request (E:\Bot Discord\Francis le Bot\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\index.js:1266:22)
    at async StringSelectMenuInteraction.reply (E:\Bot Discord\Francis le Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\interfaces\InteractionResponses.js:111:5)
    at async InteractionCollector.<anonymous> (E:\Bot Discord\Francis le Bot\commands\utils\setnotifs.js:173:29) {
  requestBody: {
    files: [],
    json: {
      type: 4,
      data: {
        content: 'Les notifications TikTok ont bien été configurées ! ✅',
        tts: false,
        nonce: undefined,
        embeds: undefined,
        components: undefined,
        username: undefined,
        avatar_url: undefined,
        allowed_mentions: undefined,
        flags: undefined,
        message_reference: undefined,
        attachments: undefined,
        sticker_ids: undefined,
        thread_name: undefined
      }
    }
  },
  rawError: { message: 'Unknown interaction', code: 10062 },
  code: 10062,
  status: 404,
  method: 'POST',
  url: 'https://discord.com/api/v10/interactions/1237745806162001970/aW50ZXJhY3Rpb246MTIzNzc0NTgwNjE2MjAwMTk3MDo0REczcDN6Q1FLMGZLeFpLOVJ5UFFvWGRJeVp3TFZWS01tcjBQNk1FT0p2TDkwQUtPTFd2TU45QUZHYTBpb2lDVU5RVEc0d1Z1c0JKUzNha1dpdjFOR2tqOVdhdm9VYlA0SXVwZ0xKeXJaMk54YXlXTjltZ3c0VWVoOUduV0ZvOA/callback'
}

I'm a beginner and I don't at all where this error comes from. Do you have any idea? Here's my code:
const { SlashCommandBuilder, StringSelectMenuBuilder, StringSelectMenuOptionBuilder, ActionRowBuilder, ChannelType, ChannelSelectMenuBuilder } = require('discord.js');
const fs = require('fs'); 
const configFile = './config.json';


module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('setnotifs')
        .setDescription('Définir dans quel salon envoyer les notifications relatives à Killame')
        .setDMPermission(false),

    async run(interaction, client) {
        const select = new StringSelectMenuBuilder()
            .setCustomId('notification_select')
            .setPlaceholder('Sélectionnez une option')
            .addOptions([
                new StringSelectMenuOptionBuilder()
                    .setLabel(' Twitch')
                    .setDescription('Paramétrer les notifs Twitch')
                    .setValue('twitch'),
                new StringSelectMenuOptionBuilder()
                    .setLabel(' Youtube rediff')
                    .setDescription('Paramétrer les notifs de la chaîne rediff')
                    .setValue('youtuber'),
                new StringSelectMenuOptionBuilder()
                    .setLabel(' Youtube')
                    .setDescription('Paramétrer les notifications Youtube')
                    .setValue('youtube'),
                new StringSelectMenuOptionBuilder()
                    .setLabel(' Tiktok')
                    .setDescription('Paramétrer les notifications TikTok')
                    .setValue('tiktok')
            ]);

        const row = new ActionRowBuilder()
        .addComponents(select);

        await interaction.reply({
            content: 'Quelles notifications voulez-vous configurer ? ',
            components: [row]
        });

        const filter = (interaction) => interaction.isStringSelectMenu() && interaction.customId === 'notification_select';
        const collector = interaction.channel.createMessageComponentCollector({ filter, time: 15000 }); 

        collector.on('collect', async (interaction) => {
            const selectedValue = interaction.values[0];

            switch (selectedValue) {
                case 'twitch':

                    const select = new ChannelSelectMenuBuilder()
                    .setCustomId('channel_select')
                    .setPlaceholder('Choisisez un channel')
                    .setMinValues(1)
                    .setMaxValues(1)
                    .setChannelTypes(ChannelType.GuildText)
                    

                    const row = new ActionRowBuilder()
                    .addComponents(select);
                
                    await interaction.reply({
                        content: 'Dans quel salon voulez-vous que les notifs soient envoyées ? ',
                        components: [row]
                    });

                    const filter = (interaction) => interaction.customId === 'channel_select';
                    const collector = interaction.channel.createMessageComponentCollector({ filter, time: 15000}) 

                    collector.on('collect', async (interaction) => {
                        const selectedChannelId = interaction.values[0];

                        const config = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(configFile, 'utf-8'));
                        config.discord.notificationChannelTwitch = selectedChannelId;
                        fs.writeFileSync(configFile, JSON.stringify(config, null, 2));

                        await interaction.reply('Les notifications Twitch ont bien été configurées ! ✅');
                    });


                    break;
                case 'youtuber':

                const select1 = new ChannelSelectMenuBuilder()
                .setCustomId('channel_select')
                .setPlaceholder('Choisisez un channel')
                .setMinValues(1)
                .setMaxValues(1)
                .setChannelTypes(ChannelType.GuildText)

                    const row1 = new ActionRowBuilder()
                    .addComponents(select1);

                    await interaction.reply({
                        content: 'Dans quel salon voulez-vous que les notifs soient envoyées ? ',
                        components: [row1]
                    }); 
                


                    const filter1 = (interaction) => interaction.customId === 'channel_select';
                    const collector1 = interaction.channel.createMessageComponentCollector({ filter1, time: 15000}) 

                    collector1.on('collect', async (interaction) => {
                        const selectedChannelId = interaction.values[0];

                        const config = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(configFile, 'utf-8'));
                        config.discord.notificationChannelYtbRedif = selectedChannelId;
                        fs.writeFileSync(configFile, JSON.stringify(config, null, 2));

                        await interaction.reply('Les notifications Youtube Rediff ont bien été configurées ! ✅');
                    });
                    break;
                case 'youtube':
                    
                const select3 = new ChannelSelectMenuBuilder()
                .setCustomId('channel_select')
                .setPlaceholder('Choisisez un channel')
                .setMinValues(1)
                .setMaxValues(1)
                .setChannelTypes(ChannelType.GuildText)

                    const row3 = new ActionRowBuilder()
                    .addComponents(select3);
                
                    await interaction.reply({
                        content: 'Dans quel salon voulez-vous que les notifs soient envoyées ? ',
                        components: [row3]
                    });

                    const filter3 = (interaction) => interaction.customId === 'channel_select';
                    const collector3 = interaction.channel.createMessageComponentCollector({ filter3, time: 15000}) 

                    collector3.on('collect', async (interaction) => {
                        const selectedChannelId = interaction.values[0];

                        const config = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(configFile, 'utf-8'));
                        config.discord.notificationChannelYtb = selectedChannelId;
                        fs.writeFileSync(configFile, JSON.stringify(config, null, 2));

                        await interaction.reply('Les notifications Youtube ont bien été configurées ! ✅');
                    });
                    break;
                case 'tiktok':
                                        
                    const select2 = new ChannelSelectMenuBuilder()
                    .setCustomId('channel_select')
                    .setPlaceholder('Choisisez un channel')
                    .setMinValues(1)
                    .setMaxValues(1)
                    .setChannelTypes(ChannelType.GuildText)
    
                        const row2 = new ActionRowBuilder()
                        .addComponents(select2)
                    
                        await interaction.reply({
                            content: 'Dans quel salon voulez-vous que les notifs soient envoyées ? ',
                            components: [row2]
                        }); 
                        
    
                        const filter2 = (interaction) => interaction.customId === 'channel_select';
                        const collector2 = interaction.channel.createMessageComponentCollector({ filter2, time: 15000}) 
    
                        collector2.on('collect', async (interaction) => {
                            const selectedChannelId = interaction.values[0];
        
                            const config = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(configFile, 'utf-8'));
                            config.discord.notificationChannelTikTok = selectedChannelId;
                            fs.writeFileSync(configFile, JSON.stringify(config, null, 2));
    
                            await interaction.reply('Les notifications TikTok ont bien été configurées ! ✅');
                        });
                        break;             
                default:
                    break;
            }
        });

        collector.on('end', (collected) => {
            if (collected.size === 0) {
                interaction.followUp('Aucune interactions détectée, merci de recommencer.');
            }
        });
    },
};

I answer to the interaction immediately so, I've tried to put interaction.deferReply() and editReply but it doesn't work either.

Every time the command runs you're creating new collectors and never destroying them, meaning you're trying to respond to interactions that have already been responded to causing your error. You can use Collector#stop once you have replied to the interaction or set a max number of interactions when creating the collector.
